# Purpose of multiple branches for Gatsby and GitHub Pages

Tags: git, github, github-pages, gatsby

I've followed two guides to make a blog using Gatsby and GitHub Pages.

- [Gatsby's official documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/how-gatsby-works-with-github-pages/)
- And a great [guide](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-write-a-blog-using-gatsby-from-your-phone-e92a99851a04) from a member of the FreeCodeCamp community.

Both guides reference multiple branches existing within a GitHub pages repo (e.g. a gh-pages branch and a master branch). Conceptually, I'm unsure why this is necessary and I'm particularly confused by the following quote.

> Because GitHub Page serves content from the master branch, you will
>   need to deploy the content of the public folder generated by the yarn
>   build command to the master branch. We will need to put our source
>   code into another branch. We’ll call it develop.

What kind of workflow are we aiming to achieve? For example...

1. Make a change to the blog content (gh-pages branch)
2. Commit the change
3. Build and deploy
4. ...Where does Master come into play?

In my repo, GitHub says, "Master is 3 commits ahead, 9 commits behind gh-pages." Clearly, I'm in the mud. Thank you in advance for any insight.

Comment: Nice way to ask the question. Good approach. I am not sure how it works. But still it clearly says " you will need to deploy the content of the public folder generated by the yarn build command to the master branch". Commit your source code to develop branch. Do a yarn build. Commit the content public folder to master branch. This is what I understood from that message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first question can be explained by the nature of the GitHub repository, as explained in "[Configuring a publishing source for GitHub Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/)"

> If your site is a User or Organization Page that has a repository named `<username>.github.io` or `<orgname>.github.io` , you cannot publish your site's source files from different locations.
>   User and Organization Pages that have this type of repository name are only published from the `master` branch.
>
> For more information about the different types of GitHub Pages sites, see "[User, Organization, and Project Pages.](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages)"

The [last link includes the updated instructions](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#publishing-sources-for-github-pages-sites) for Q1 2020 (compared to Q4 2018)

> The default publishing source for user and organization sites is the `master` branch.
>   If the repository for your user or organization site has a `master` branch, your site will publish automatically from that branch.
>   You cannot choose a different publishing source for user or organization sites.
>
> The default publishing source for a project site is the `gh-pages` branch.
>   If the repository for your project site has a `gh-pages` branch, your site will publish automatically from that branch.
>
> Project sites can also be published from the `master` branch or a `/docs` folder on the `master` branch.
>   To publish your site from one of these sources, you must configure a different publishing source

Comment: Looks like this quoted information isn't at that link anymore, so thank you for putting the text of the quote in your answer.

Comment: @lauren.marietta True. I have edited the answer for include up-to-date instructions.